# Selenium(python) scripts started failing a couple of days ago. Fails at the first find_element()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is the beginning of the code, and the relevant function where the script errors out.

```
import keyring


import time
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import os
import shutil

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
from Navisphere_email_script import sendCsvFile

today = date.today()
year = today.year
month = today.month
day = today.day
# maybe use the file server instead

downloadPath = "C:\\PythonAutomation\\CHRobinsonNavisphere\\excel_files\\{}\\{}\\{}\\".format(year,month,day)
if not os.path.exists(downloadPath):
        os.makedirs(downloadPath)

#login using keyring
servicename = 'chrobinson'
username = 'genericusername'
password = keyring.get_password(servicename, username)


options = Options()
# Fetch the centralized ChromeDriver path from the environment variable
centralized_chromedriver_path = 'C:\\PythonAutomation\\chromedriver.exe'
service = Service(executable_path=centralized_chromedriver_path)


options.binary_location= 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\Application\\chrome.exe'
#options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('==no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

prefs = {"download.default_directory" : downloadPath}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)


def login_navisphere():  
    
    
    browser.get('https://navisphere.chrobinson.com/login.aspx')
    
    
    time.sleep(30)
    

    ###  TTHIS IS THE ORIGINAL ONE, WITH AN ATTEMPT TO USE THE MORE EXPLICIT XPATH
    username_elem = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/form/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]/input') #'//*[@id="OnlineLogin1_txUserName"]')

    #### HERE IS A SEPERATE ATTEMPT TO TRY TO CALL IT BY ID
    #username_elem = browser.find_element(By.ID, "OnlineLogin1_txUserName")
    username_elem.send_keys(username)
    password_elem = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="OnlineLogin1_txtPassword"]')
    password_elem.send_keys(password)
    login_elem = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="loginOKtaBtn"]')
    login_elem.click()
    time.sleep(15)
    return
```

Here is the error code:

```
File C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\spyder_kernels\\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\\pythonautomation\\chrobinsonnavisphere\\navisphere_main.py:114
main()

File c:\\pythonautomation\\chrobinsonnavisphere\\navisphere_main.py:110 in main
run_selenium()

File c:\\pythonautomation\\chrobinsonnavisphere\\navisphere_main.py:105 in run_selenium
login_navisphere()

File c:\\pythonautomation\\chrobinsonnavisphere\\navisphere_main.py:69 in login_navisphere
username_elem = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/form/div\[4\]/div/div\[2\]/div\[1\]/div/span\[2\]/input') #'//\*\[@id="OnlineLogin1_txUserName"\]')

File C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py:738 in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})\["value"\]

File C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py:344 in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\errorhandler.py:229 in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: unknown error: result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response
(Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.9)
```

I tried different ways to find the element i am looking for, in this case it is the username. It never gets pass the username.

The chrome driver is the latest one, and I can't download a later one. It isn't failing the same as when whenever I do need to update the driver.

All my selenium scripts have started failing in exactly the same way. Like they can't read the page. This only started Oct/08/2023. Otherwise, they have all been running reliably for a year.

Comment: servers sometimes change HTML/JS code on page - to make it more modern, or to fix some problems - and then your code may now work and you may have to write your code again.

Comment: You have `==no-sandbox` instead of `--no-sandbox`, but that shouldn't change things.

Comment: They may be checking the User-Agent more closely.  If you fetch that page with `wget` or `curl`, you'll see that you don't get the login page.  Why are you using a Chrome Beta?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I actually do not remember why I am using Chrome beta. I think it just happened and I ran with it. I was going to try to switch to a different driver or browser next. 

I just wanted to see what may be going on before I make that switch. 

and if they are checking the User-Agent more closely, were they in cahoots with every other site I have a script for? they all stopped working on the same day with the same error.

Comment: Suspicious.  Could be a problem with the Chrome Beta.  Perhaps back down to regular Chrome.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I skipped the going to regular Chrome portion and just went  straight for Firefox. 

It is working now, but I still don't know what that error was all about. Any time I had a problem with the driver, I wasn't able to open the browser.

Comment: I have the same problem does somebody else have an idea?

For some reason I can get firefoxdriver to run ;-(

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by installing the 119 version of chromedriver.exe.

https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/119.0.6045.105/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

Comment: I have this problem despite having that exact chrome version, although on linux

Comment: Update I had chrome 119.0.6045.105 but chromedriver was 118. After updating it seems to work again.

Comment: I had the same problem on Mac and using Capybara (with Ruby). Updating chromedriver to v119 did indeed fix it

Answer (score 0):

I spent all day toiling with this same problem that only occurred this week. Here is how I solved it:

1. Download Google Chrome for testing (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable). Add location to environment variables item: 'Path'. Without this the line `browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)` uses your default browser instead of the testing browser. I never had to do this step before.
2. Download and save Chrome Driver (also https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable). Add location to environment variables item: 'Path.
3. Install Selenium (can be done within Python interpreter PyCharm). I had to uninstall the old version because a simple update wouldn't work.
4. Restart system to capture the environment variables change.

[Chrome for Testing and Chrome Driver links (be sure to get both)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB7VQ.png)

[New Path variables that point to Driver and Chrome for Test directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z6eu.png)